# Send templates emails Django 1.11 error (html tags in letter)

Tags: django, django-templates, django-email

I am trying to send template emails.

**Code**:

```
def send_admin_notification(ticket):
    subject = "Notification: NEW TICKET."
    to = [DEFAULT_ADMIN_EMAIL]
    from_email = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
    template = 'emails/admin.html'
    ctx = {
        "ticket_id": ticket.id,
        "subject": ticket.subject,
        "text": ticket.support_text,
        "email": ticket.email,
    }
    message = render_to_string(template, ctx)
    msg = EmailMessage(subject, message, to=to, from_email=from_email)
    msg.send()
```

But the letter comes with all html tags how to send letter without html tags ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/email/#emailmessage-objects) for `EmailMessage`:

> **body**: The body text. **This should be a plain text message.**

To send HTML messages, you need to use `django.core.mail.EmailMultiAlternatives` instead of `EmailMessage`. The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/email/#sending-alternative-content-types) provides an example that includes a HTML message.

Alternatively you can use [`django.core.mail.send_mail`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/email/#send-mail) which accepts a `html_message` argument, something like this:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

def send_admin_notification(ticket):
    subject = "Notification: NEW TICKET."
    from_email = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
    tpl= 'emails/admin.html'

    html_message = render_to_string(tpl, ctx)

    send_mail(
        subject=subject ,
        message='', # Plain text version of message - advisable to provide this
        from_email=from_email
        recipient_list=[DEFAULT_ADMIN_EMAIL],
        html_message=html_message
    )
```